# theorem that says all homogeneous equations are consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

Is there a theorem that states all homogeneous equations are consistent? I know its true, I just need to quote something so I don't need to do a "official" proof for it.

Also, how can I prove that an equation is homogeneous? 
    Ax+By=0
is homogeneous, can I just say it is homogeneous or do I need to prove it? If I do, how would I do it?

Comment: A proof takes much less space than that quote would take...

Comment: When I say quote I mean "Via the Theorem of blah blah blah"

Comment: What makes you think I didn't understand that? Do you know the _definition_ of the word "consistent"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just say that all homogeneous system of equations are consistent since they have the trivial solution $\vec{0}$.

For the second question, it is homogeneous by definition, which says that a homogeneous linear equation has constant term $0$.